# OpenGL: Add vertices with vertex shader

Tags: opengl, shader, vertex

Tell me, please, how I can add new vertex in vertex shader?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vertex shader only transforms vertices. If you need to output additional geometry based on the input vertices a [geometry shader](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader) is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can add vertices using a geometry shader http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader

"A GS can create new primitives, unlike vertex shaders, which are limited to a 1:1 input to output ratio."

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  That's what [geometry shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_shader) are for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create new vertices using a vertex shader; it can only *transform* vertices. The [Khronos documentation for the vertex shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) states:

> A vertex shader receives a single vertex from the vertex stream and generates a single vertex to the output vertex stream. There must be a 1:1 mapping from input vertices to output vertices.

There are several options for adding new vertices:

- Generate the new vertices on the CPU before rendering them.
- Use a geometry shader for creating new vertices based on a given primitive.
- Use tessellation for creating new vertices based on a given patch.